Remove firefox form field highlight?
I'm having this problem with firefox form fields. They're suddenly highlighting in bright, ugly blue, and I'm trying to get it back to the original, more clean dotted line. Actually, at this point, from all the css modifications I've been trying, I would settle for none at all or a change of color and size.
What I'm talking about:

What I'd like:

What code I have used in userChrome.css/userContent.css:
button {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    -moz-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    -o-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}

input:focus {outline:none;}

input[type=text]:focus {outline:none;}

input {border:0; outline:none;}

input {box-shadow:none;}

input:focus {
outline: none !important;
border: none important!
border-color: #ccc;
box-shadow: none important!
}

@-moz-document url-prefix("http://"), url-prefix("https://") {
    input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    outline: none !important;}

input[type="checkbox"], *:focus {
    accent-color: transparent !important;}

input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus, button:focus, input {
    accent-color: transparent !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

I've also tried modifying the following in about:config:
browser.display.focus_ring_on_anything
browser.display.focus_ring_width
browser.display.always_show_rings_after_key_focus

Nothing works. I'm going to pull my hair out. The blue highlight is disturbing and gaudy, not to mention messes up the style of the pages. I want the element gone, it is not needed, or at the very least the color changed. How would I do this without simply not using firefox any longer?

Is the page your own? If not, it's possible that the author is overriding default styling. Can you post a minimal, reproducible example of the problem? Although it's frowned upon here, can you post a link to the page where you see the problem?

@nanigashi It's on every page that uses a default, non-styled form/search field/radio box, etc. All the custom ones I have no problem with. It's Firefox's default bright blue setting. I can override the color, even make it transparent, but not its size. That website used as an example was a random website. Any site that uses a default form field you will find it.

Firefox's default formatting is easily replaced by userContent.css. I am unable to reproduce your inability to do so on any web site.

I don't know what to tell you. You can literally go to w3schools css forms and select any of them to see it. It's the same with waterfox, palemoon, etc using no custom css rules.

For example then, w3schools CSS forms page uses some focus styling specified by w3schools in an inline (style tag) stylesheet for that page. A userContent.css of ":focus-visible,
:focus {
outline: 2px dotted #888;
}" (the answer you rejected) overrides browser default outlining to produce the result that you say you want. It just works. If it doesn't work for you, then you have something else going on that is not included in your question.

You could try adding -moz-appearance:none; for all input fields. That should turn off the styling and enforce a standardized primitive appearance.
